# Is it OK to say "And I begin" for current action?

Tags: sentence-construction, idiomatic-language

Some person is about to begin some process. Can he say "And I begin" when he's ready to start?, like "And I'm starting it" or "And here we go".

Comment: I am on it! I will get started (on it) now! I will start (on it) now!

Comment: The first two aren't something native English speakers would really say.  Try  "Let's get started" or "Let's begin".  "So, here we go".

Comment: It's not great, but the preferred phrase would depend a lot on context, e.g. how serious and important the work is, and if you're doing a long series of delicate operations, or just a single thing to kick the process off. Whether it's truly starting from scratch or you've already assembled your materials and done your preparatory work; whether it's science, sports, art, cookery. Etc. You wouldn't use the same saying if you were starting a wedding, performing brain surgery, embalming a corpse, launching a military attack, beginning a rugby game, climbing a hill, cooking dinner...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in a friendly, and less stilted, way you could say "So, if you are all sitting comfortably (looking around you with a smile to ensure there is no one who isn't) then I'll begin".

Edit 22/1/23
Those who have downvoted may not be aware of the origin of this opening. It was the form that was always used by the reader of the story, in the BBC radio programme "Listen with Mother" - circa 1950. So the significance is perhaps wasted on anyone currently aged less than seventy!

Answer (score -1):

Being a native American I'd say it sounds like you're an immigrant who just learned how to speak English.

Some other ways of saying it:

- I'll go ahead
- Let's begin/start
- I'll begin/start